# Terraform lookup function - Error: Expected to be number, actual type is String

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using Terraform in order to build some AWS VPC components like the `aws_route` below.

I'm trying to scale the number of NAT gateways dynamically with the [`count`](https://www.terraform.io/intro/examples/count.html) parameter:

```
resource "aws_route" "my_nat_gw" {
  route_table_id         = "${var.rt_id}"
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  nat_gateway_id         = "${nat_gw_id}"

  #I have an error here - on the "lookup" term
  count = "${length(var.azs) * lookup(map(var.enable_nat_gateway, 1), "true", 0)}"
}
```

For the sake of brevity let's ignore the part of `length(var.azs)` in the `count` calculation.

I'm getting the following error on the `lookup(map(var....)` part:

> Expected to be number, actual type is String more

The `enable_nat_gateway` variable is boolean.

I tried also the following:

```
lookup(map(true, 1), true, 0)}
lookup(map("true", 1), "true", 0)}
```

But still no good.

*Any idea how to fix it?*

---

Some calculations for those who are not familiar with the [map](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/map.html) and [lookup](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/lookup.html) syntax:

If the `enable_nat_gateway` is equal to **true** then `'map' is equal to{true=1}` and the total lookup term should be equal to **1**.

Else:

If the `enable_nat_gateway` is equal to **false** then `'map' is equal to{true=0}` and the total lookup term should be equal to **0**.

---

Notice that I'm using Terraform 0.11.11 so the `map` function is still supported.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? Just to add a route to the route table if the NAT gateway exists? Why do you want one for each AZ in the same route table?

Comment: This is part of a module and I want it to be set dynamically according to specific demand.

Comment: Yes but why do you want multiple routes to the same NAT Gateway in the same route table?

Comment: This is why I didn't add all the code - so the answer will be specific to the error (:
But anyway, I'm creating multiple subnets, each with its own routing tables, routes and NAT gateway.

Comment: As it is, the code in the question doesn't fit the [mcve] criteria because it's not complete enough for anyone to run to see your issue. Ultimately though your count is way over complicated for no benefit. You'd be better with a proper ternary statement such as `count = "${var.enable_nat_gateway ? length(var.azs) : 0}"`.

Comment: Thanks @ydaetskcoR, but as you probably know - in order for this question to be suitable for the "Complete" part of the "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable" criteria I would have to had a lot of irrelevant code which would make the question very long. So I preferred going for the "Minimal" part  of the criteria. 
In order to reproduce my problem you don't need all my code, you could just play with the "count" calculation.  Thank you again (:

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to conditionally add *n* route resources then you should be using a [ternary statement](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#conditionals) here with something like:

```
resource "aws_route" "my_nat_gw" {
  count = "${var.enable_nat_gateway ? length(var.azs) : 0}"

  route_table_id         = "${var.rt_id}"
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  nat_gateway_id         = "${var.nat_gw_id}"
}
```

This checks if the `enable_nat_gateway` variable evaluates to `true` and if so creates a resource for each element in the `azs` variable. If it's not true then it won't create any resources.

Comment: looking good, but I'll wait a bit more for a possible solution to the original problem. It might help other people facing the same error in the future.

Comment: That syntax is crazily complicated and comes from hacks prior to Terraform adding ternary statements which were never stable. If you really want to use that hack then you can probably get away with something like `count = "${length(var.azs) * var.enable_nat_gateway}"` and rely on the fact that booleans are just 0/1 integers except for when they get mangled to strings at which point you're basically stuck.